Choosing the Starting Point of Induction
I am a self-study student learning the basics of math proofs. During my studies, I encountered the following question:

(For all n $\ge$ 3)
I completed the problem using weak induction (with a singular base case of n = 3) and with a basic understanding of Pascal's triangle. Upon solving, though, I was struck by a question. What if, instead, we were asked to prove the same theorem for all n $\ge$ 0? Technically, if we express the right hand side as a summation, then inputs of n = 0, n = 1, and n = 2 equal to 0. In that case, would I have four base cases (n = 0, n = 1, n = 2, n = 3)? In another scenario, suppose we were asked to prove the same theorem for all n $\ge$ 4? Would I have a single base case (n = 4)? I point out all this to say: How do I navigate deciding base cases? If my guesses are correct, how come I have three more base cases than the original proof when I consider n $\ge$ 0 but the same number of base cases as the original proof when I consider n $\ge$ 4?
My exploration of this concept has also challenged my previous understanding of weak induction. Throughout my schooling, I was taught that weak induction would always have a single base case, whereas strong induction may have one or more base cases. However, if this problem does indeed have more than one base case, then this generalization does not hold.

This is impossible to say without seeing your proof (and if it still works if you found it on the base case $n = 0$), but generally speaking you simply split the proof into the "boring" case $n = 0, 1, 2$ and the interesting case $n \geq 3$, which you then prove by (weak) induction on the base case $n = 3$.

There more practical aspect is that we don't usually distinguish between different forms of induction in mathematical practice. You just do "proofs by induction:" You say "here's some finite amount of base cases I'm going to use, here's my induction step $n \to n + 1$ (in which you rely on as much information as you need, either just the $n$ case or all the $k \leq n$ cases or a subset thereof)" and go to town, and never worry if what you did was weak or strong induction in the end (in fact I actually had to look these terms up because they're not familiar to me).

I am not sure why such a fuss is made about a marginal distinction. It serves only to confuse, in my opinion.

I'm not sure how relevant this is for your concerns, but for weak induction you can think of the situation as you have a countably-infinite ordered sequence of statements -- 1st, 2nd, 3rd, ... OR 10th, 12th, 14th, ... OR 1st, 4th, 9th, 16th, 25th, ... OR 2nd, 3rd, 5th, 7th, 11th, 13th, ... OR whatever. You separately prove a certain finitely many consecutive initial statements (one-by-one, or maybe some or all collectively in some way; usually it's only the first statement), and use induction to take care of the remaining tail of assumptions.

It's still weak induction, with a single base case, but it's perhaps not just weak induction.
First of all, "I was taught X" is generally a bad justification when it comes to mathematics, so let's see why people say that weak induction only has a single base case. To that end, what even is weak induction? It's the following proof scheme:
Let $F(n)$ be some statement depending on an integer $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ as input. Given some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, we want to show that $F(n)$ is true for all $n > k$, and do this as follows:

We establish that $F(k)$ is true.
We establish that if $F(n)$ is true for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then it is also true for $F(n + 1)$.
We conclude that $F(n)$ is true for all $n \geq k$.

This by definition only has a single base case, namely $F(k)$, but let's say we want a second base case $F(k')$ for some $k' \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then either $k' > k$, in which case $k' - k$ applications of step 2 already prove $F(k')$, or vice versa (the case $k' = k$ is of course uninteresting), in which case, assuming that our initial induction can be extended to start at $F(k')$, a similar $k - k'$ applications of step 2 prove $F(k)$.
Long story short, if you have more than one base case, then iterating the induction step from the "lowest" one already proves all the others, so you didn't need to bother proving anything than the lowest base case to begin with.
Okay, so in your case you now have what appears to be four base cases, not one. I claim this is still weak induction, but it may not be as "pure" as in the original problem. Essentially there's two possibilities, depending on what your proof looks like: Either your proof for the $n \geq 3$ case works flawlessly when you replace the $n = 3$ base case with $n = 0$, or, despite the fact that the cases $n = 0, 1, 2$ are all true, your proof only works for $n \geq 3$. In this latter case, you don't have weak induction with four base cases: You have a case distinction into three trivial cases you deal with separately and a weak induction for $n \geq 3$. In particular, the induction is not based on the cases $n = 0, 1, 2$: they don't influence the induction at all, and calling them base cases should not sit quite right with you.

...but really, in practice nobody cares.
We don't distinguish between different types of induction in day to day mathematics. Weak induction is a special case of strong induction anyway, and once you've understood the underlying principle, how these proofs work becomes pretty much second nature. As for "how do I navigate deciding base cases," I think the takeaway here should be something like the following:
Suppose you're given some statement you're supposed to prove using some (specified or unspecified) kind of induction. At this point, make a decision to either tackle the induction step first or work out a few base cases. If you can manage the former directly, it should tell you more or less what base cases you need, but often it's smarter to try and figure out a few potential base cases to get a feel for the problem. In any cases, you may end up with some sort of induction step and a few potential base cases; the last step is then to think through which of the base cases you actually need and which you can discard. Finally, you need to deal with all cases not covered by the induction separately, as special cases (like above).

Thank you for such a thorough response!

+1 I like your last heading :-)
